# Compiler error after renaming XCode 5.1 project

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5, xcode5.1

I renamed a project file from **TopPlaces** to **TopRegions** in XCode. After renaming it and cleaning up file locations and references, I can "clean" the file in XCode without any trouble, but when I go to compile it, I get the following error.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/iOSPadawan/Documents/Developer/Stanford iOS 7/TopRegions/TopPlaces/ImageVC.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I tried deleting the view controller referenced in the error and reimporting it from the original (pre-renamed) project, but that doesn't take care of the error.

I did a text search of "Build Settings" and "Build Phases" of the project to TopPlaces, but it turns up nothing. However, under Compile Sources in Build Settings, I see references (that don't turn up in text search) to the old project name. I've tried removing them and adding the implementation files back, but I still get the same error.

I knew I'm missing something really ****ing noobish, but I don't know what? Any suggestions? Here's a complete listing from the compiler error:

```
CompileC /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageVC.o TopPlaces/ImageVC.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Users/iOSPadawan/Documents/Developer/Stanford iOS 7/TopRegions"
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/TopRegions-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/TopRegions-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/TopRegions-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/TopRegions-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/TopRegions-Prefix-gvxkjoatgnwponegpmitcljtrjli/TopRegions-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageVC.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageVC.dia -c /Users/iOSPadawan/Documents/Developer/Stanford\ iOS\ 7/TopRegions/TopPlaces/ImageVC.m -o /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageVC.o
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I don't understand, the compiler didn't update the sources for the new project name, despite the fact I updated their locations in file inspector. I was able to resolve the problem by nuking the references (NOT the files) in the project navigator and dragging them back in from Finder.

“Experience is merely the name men gave to their mistakes.”
― Oscar Wilde